# GDB crashes trying to display pretty-printed std::vector

Tags: c++, gdb, stdvector, pretty-print

how to avoid GDB crashing or hanging when entering a function step by step and GDB pretty printing for example STL vector which has not been stepped over to be initialized.

For example pretty printing a vector that is not initialized in function can show over millions of elements, but that due to uninitialized value inside a vector, which hasn't been stepped over. Immediately when i step over line the vector holds 0 elements.

Any way to avoid this?

Comment: The best way to avoid this is to update to the current version of gdb, if possible. It's also been my experience that gdb was prone to crashing, when attempting to swallow a bitter C++-based pill. It hasn't done that, for me, in some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any way to avoid this?

The best way to avoid this is by *not* displaying contents of a `vector` until it has been initialized.

If you are doing it via `display` GDB command, *don't*.

If this is happening because your GUI does it, don't use that GUI.

Comment: I am using visualGDB with visual studio... of course you cannot presuade microsoft to do it differently